# Is there a way to read data from csv using numpy.genfromtxt from a given directory?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, input, argparse

I'm supposed to read in a csv filepath through argparse. So path of a csv file is args.X for example, how do I go about loading this data into a 2d numpy array? For now I was using `Data = np.genfromtxt(args.X, delimiter=",")`, this works when args.X contains the file name instead of path and the file is in same folder as the python script. How do I read when the data is not in the same folder and I have been given a path instead to the file?

Comment: Does it throw any error? Is it `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: my path is  D:\Amit\ell409\2019anz1787\gaussian.csv which i give as input, and the error is "D:Amitell4092019anz1787gaussian.csv not found"

Comment: That's not a valid path in Windows... I think you meant `D:\\Amitell4092019anz1787gaussian.csv ` right?

Comment: *all* the backslashes are getting killed.  I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are having problems with backslashes disappearing, which is odd.  Regardless, you're probably better off telling argparse you want a `Path` object (and using one).  You probably want code something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("IN", type=Path)
parser.parse_args()

inf = args.IN.expanduser().resolve()
if not inf.exists():
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"No such file: {inf}")
Data = np.genfromtxt(inf, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: thank you! this works

Comment: feel free to accept if it does :)  As a shot in the dark I think some string escaping was going wrong, as you were missing *any* slashes in the error message.  But in general use Path for paths, it's *much* easier

Comment: yes turns out the slashes were being discarded as a result of some escape sequence